# Task progress is not updated latest status on Celery+RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I implemented progress feedback of long task with [custom states](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states) on Celery + RabbitMQ result backend.

But the caller can't retrive the latest progess status as I expected. In following code, `result.info['step']` *always* return `0`, and then the task will be finished with "result=42".

```
# tasks.py -- celery worker
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def long_task():
  for i in range(0, 10):
    timer.sleep(10)  # some work
    self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'step': i})
  return 42


# caller.py
from tasks import long_task
result = long_task.delay()

while not (result.successful() or result.failed()):
  try:
    result.get(timeout=1)
  except celery.exceptions.TimeoutError:
    if result.state == 'PROGRESS':
      print("progress={}".format(result.info['step']))
print("result={}".format(result.get()))
```

Python 3.4.1 / Celery 3.1.17 / RabbitMQ 3.4.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a subtle timing issue, combined with the fact that the [RabbitMQ result backend](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#rabbitmq-result-backend) sends task results as messages and can only be retrieved once.

Short answer upfront: avoid calling `result.get()` until you really need the final result:

```
while not result.ready():
  if result.state == "PROGRESS":
    print("progress={}".format(result.info['step']))
  time.sleep(1)
print("result={}".format(result.get()))
# +additional cleanup: see comments below
```

The longer answer is that there are really two kinds of methods (and a property) in play here which talks to the AMQP backend:

- [`AsyncResult.get()`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get)

  Calls [`AMQPBackend.wait_for()`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/backends/amqp.html#AMQPBackend.wait_for), which consumes all results from the queue for the task until a result with a state in `celery.states.READY_STATES` comes in.
- `AsyncResult.successful()`, `AsyncResult.failed()`, `AsyncResult.info`

  Calls [`AMQPBackend.get_task_meta()`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/backends/amqp.html#AMQPBackend.get_task_meta), which consumes all results from the queue for the task, then caches and returns the latest one. If no messages were retrieved, the backend returns a cached result or a `PENDING` result. Note: the latest message is [requeued](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v3.1.17/celery/backends/amqp.py#L184) by the backend, and if it's [the final result](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v3.1.17/celery/result.py#L333), it will be cached by the `AsyncResult` instance<sup>1</sup>.

Calling `result.get()` will consume all state updates, giving no chance for `result.info` to provide an up-to-date progress report; instead it will most likely be a stale cache, which one of the calls to `AsyncResult.get_task_meta()` managed to grab at some point.

So, depending on the timing, the `step` can be stuck at 0 in the next-to-worst case scenario, where the worst one is the `PROGRESS` state never reaching the caller.

<sup>1</sup>Because the final result is both requeued and cached when fetched through a call to `get_task_meta()`, you'll need to manually drain the queue as noted in the comment below.

Comment: The problem was solved! But it cause another problem that RabbitMQ doesn't automatically delete "result queue" because of unconsumed final 'SUCCESS' message. Here is dirty ad-hoc workaround: `result.backend.wait_for(task_id=result.task_id, cache=False)`.

Comment: I've updated the answer about why the final message is left in the queue. This is probably unintended behavior.